# Not getting the right width and height in ImgGrab

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pynput, python

So im trying to get an image based on two clicks, the top left and lower right corners, but when i give the widht and height to the ImgGrab function I recive diferent values from the original, how can I fix that?

I figure that when i set the top left corner to (0, 0) of my display i get the correct values, but at any other place i get the wrong ones.

```
def get_pos():
    input('Place the mouse on the top left corner of your game screen and 
        press enter ')
    topleft = mouse.position
    input('Do the same, but in the lower right corner')
    lowerright = mouse.position
    print('to start/stop running the program press "M", to exit the 
    program press "ESC"')
    ref = (lowerright[0] - topleft[0], lowerright[1] - topleft[1])
    pos_click = [(ref[0]*0.83 + topleft[0], ref[1]*0.37 + topleft[1]), 
            (ref[0]*0.42 + topleft[0], ref[1]*0.45 + topleft[1]), 
            (ref[0]*0.84 + topleft[0], ref[1]*0.79 + topleft[1]), 
            (ref[0]*0.50 + topleft[0], ref[1]*0.75 + topleft[1]),
            (topleft), (ref)]
    return pos_click

pos_click = get_pos()

img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(pos_click[4][0], pos_click[4][1], pos_click[5] 
[0], 
pos_click[5][1])) #x, y, w, h
img_np = np.array(img)
print('tamanho de img',img, 'tamanho ref', pos_click[5])
frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I expected that img variable had the same values as `pos_click[5]`